# how to mapping two column in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

if someone can help me with this query. I have two tables(Searchbrain, SearchInitial) with **imageid**, MY idea was combine these two table according to **Primarykeyword**. Plz check the below table structure..

Table Structure.

```
Uid    Primarykeyword  ImageID 
=====  =======         =======
1      Man             123456
2      Jumping         123456
3      Beach           123456
4      Man             123457
5      Ball            123457
6      Man             123458
7      Jumping         123458
8      Beach           123458


ImageID   Color
=======   =====
123456    Red
123457    Red
123458    Red
```

how can i retrun these imageid(123456,123458) according to search man jumping beach..

Comment: Do you want to pass (as arguments a list of keywords) and then the query should search for all images that have [all] these keywords ? Why you need the second table (IamgeID,Color) ?

Comment: i want this..i need color sorting option..

Answer (score 3):

```
select ImageID 
from SearchBrain 
where Primarykeyword in ('Man','Jumping','Beach')
group by ImageID
having count(distinct Primarykeyword) = 3
```

(where 3 is the number of keywords)

Comment: You should add `group by` clause and I think It will be correct answer

Comment: @RohitKhurana Should be now I've added the group by

Comment: Currently i'm using this query :- (select ImageId from SearchInitial where Primarykeyword='Man' intersect select ImageId from SearchInitial where Primarykeyword='jumping' intersect select ImageId from SearchInitial where Primarykeyword='beach') but it's working very slow..

Comment: @RohitKhurana: If podiluska's solution is good for you then you should upvote/select this solution.